# How can I make a function where I can delete all UserDefaults data in Swift?

Tags: swift

I've tried this:

```
func deleteAllData() {
     if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Cards") {
        
    }
}
```

I don't know how to proceed. This is what I've already done thanks to tutorials online. Please help!

```
func loadData() {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Cards") {
        if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Card].self, from: data) {
            self.cards = decoded
        }
    }
 }

func saveData() {
    if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(cards) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "Cards")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `remove` the key

```
func deleteAllData() {
    self.cards = []
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Cards")
}
```